# Reactor Flux chaining, break and continue if one succeeds

Tags: java, spring-boot, rx-java, project-reactor

Use case is to try to connect to one of the backend servers, if one succeeds then thats sufficient. Is there any way to accomplish this using Reactor framework without blocking ?

For example:

```
List<String> servers = ...
Flux.fromIterable(servers)
```

This flux Should try to connect and send data to servers one by one until if there is a success.

Is there any way to accomplish this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly for this purpose there is [Flux#first](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/milestone/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#first-org.reactivestreams.Publisher...-) method.
So you need to query server and return empty flux if there is no result, so reactor will try next query and so on:

```java
    Flux.first(
        Flux.fromIterable(servers)
        .flatMap(this::queryServer)
    )
```